# .Net culture codes for many countries/currencies do not exist. How do I find the next best option?

Tags: c#, .net

E.G I cannot find a culture code for Tanzania.

This Country: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanzania

and this Currency: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanzanian_shilling

Does not exist here: 
http://timtrott.co.uk/culture-codes/
or here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441729.aspx

Is there an RSS feed that would give the next best culture code if a country/currency is not in the above two lists?

Comment: I would say to create a custom culture https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Definitely an option.

Comment: I am going to copy the same comment as an answer, so that you can set this question as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say to create a custom culture [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469(v=vs.90).aspx)